# Is there anyway to update Angular one-time bindings on a specific event?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I am working on an app with a directive that gets fed an array and then displays that array in a table. The data in the table never needs to be edited. However, users are able to search and filter the table results, at which time the entire data array is replaced. The watchers on the page can quickly get out of control, but I cannot implement one-time bindings because they cripple the search and filter functionality.

Is there anyway that I can use the one-time bindings, yet still trigger a new ng-repeat over the array when it is completely replaced?

Thanks

Comment: code please else create plunker or fiddle for your code.

Comment: You need immutable.js, really powerful!